# Unable to hide hero banner on music StackExchange site

Tags: bug, anonymous

Normally when I navigate to a SE site that I am not a member of, I hide the hero banner at the top using the "Click to hide" x button at the right-hand side.

[image: music.SE hero banner with free-hand red circle]

However this button doesn't seem to be working on music.SE. When I click on it, nothing happens. I've tried it on some other sites (retrocomputing is one I tried) and it's working fine.

Taking a look in the console though, when I click on the hide button, I get an error out of the `StackExchange.Hero()` function:

```
Uncaught TypeError: l.split is not a function
    at Object.t [as dismiss] (full-anon.en.js?v=5f531d89ce83:formatted:4556)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (what-causes-harmonics-in-an-instrument:529)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

I'm seeing this error on music.SE, but not on the other sites I've tested.

Testing this in Google Chrome 70.0.3538.110 64-bit (with all extensions disabled) on CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804

Comment: Relevant code is currently on line 7110 of the compiled JS file: https://dev.sstatic.com/Js/full-anon.en.js

Comment: This was already reported on [Music Meta](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3085).